# When to create a new function?

Tags: c#, coding-style

I had an argument with my teammate about the following.

We need to parse a symbol in a string to int(it is always a digit), this particular functionality is used in a number of places. So this can be done this way:

```
var a = int.Parse(str[i].ToString());
```

The argument was: do we need to create a function for this.

```
int ToInt(char c) {
    return int.Parse(c.ToString());
}
```

that can be used:

```
var a = ToInt(str[i]);
```

My opinion is that creating such a function is bad: it gives no benefits except for typing couple characters less (no, as we have autocomplete), but such practice increase a codebase and makes code more complecated to read by introducing additional functions. My teammate's reason is that this is more convinient to call just one such function and there is nothing bad in such a practice.

Actually question relates to a general: when it is ok(if at all) to wrapp combination of 2-3-4 functions with a new function?
So I would like to hear your opinions on that.

I argee that this is mostly defined based on personal preferences. But also I would like to hear some objective factors to define a convention for such situations in our project.

Comment: It's a personal opinion/institution-specific style convention.

Comment: `"I would like to hear your opinions"` - That's just it, this is entirely based on personal opinion.  Another option, for example, could be to write an extension method for `string` and/or `char` which could be called as: `someString.ToInt()`  Or perhaps a class for such conversions (not unlike, well, the `Convert` class which already exists).  There's really no be-all end-all technical rule on this.  Teammates can disagree on the subject for very valid, but entirely subjective, reasons.

Comment: I I'm not expert at all, but I believe that you give more work for the processor to do with the function, since will have do the same thing plus saving some thing at the stack and a new call for the function

Comment: @lazyy001 Modern compilers are smart enough to optimize it to the ground.

Comment: The only benefit it's going to give is the eventual possibility of decreasing your source file size and improving readability. When built, the compiler is likely going to break it down to the exact same subroutine. As others have pointed out, it also depends on personal opinion and institution specific coding conventions.

Comment: How much time did you spend arguing, compared to how much time you spent actually testing whether any of the arguments were true?

Comment: Not more than 5 mins for arguing :) Testing those arguments can take years I think, so I am asking here.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons to create a new sub-routine/method/function. Here is a list of just a few.

1. When the subroutine is called more than once.
2. If it makes your code easier to read/understand.
3. Personal preference.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the design can be done in many ways of course, and depends on the actual design of the whole software, readability, easy of refactoring, and encapsulation. These things are to be considered on each occasion by its own.

But on this specific case, I think its better to keep it without a function and use it as the first example for many reasons:

1. Its actually one line of code.
2. The overhead of calling a function in performance will be far more the benefit you get from making it.
3. The compiler itself probably will unwrap it again into the one line call if you make it a function, though its not always the case.

The benefit you get from doing so, will be mainly if you want to add error checking, `TryParse`, etc... in the function.